# Batch copy time creation and modification date from files using OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator, bash

First of all, I have asked the same question at stack overflow, but I am not sure if it's right over there. That's why I decided to post it here, too.

t'm having a hard time trying to copy the creation and modification date of some files to other files.

I have converted some MXF files to MOV, but unfortunately the new MOV-files don't have the same creation date.

Now I had a look around for similar questions and found different answers, but this seems to be the simplest:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for f in *.MXF; do
     touch -r "$f" "${f%MXF}mov"
    done
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me – neither with Terminal nor Automator.

I saved the Code with TextEdit. In Terminal I ran chmod+x to make the file executable and put it in the folder where my MXFs and movs are.

But I'm just getting the following error:

**touch: *.MXF: No such file or directory**

I have also tried mxf instead of MXF.

This is the output of ls- l from the test folder

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff  258458160  5 Jan  2014 570_0301.MXF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff  241431870  5 Jan  2014 570_0301.mov
-rwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff  974595120  5 Jan  2014 570_0306.MXF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff  911745994  5 Jan  2014 570_0306.mov
-rwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff  667679280  5 Jan  2014 570_0308.MXF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff  624468526  5 Jan  2014 570_0308.mov
```

Because I managed to get the modification date copied it seems that all the files already have the same date, but this doesn't cover the creation date.

Maybe someone could help me out? Will it change the modification and creation date? Because both are important...

Thank you very much in advance and all the best!

---

**EDIT:** Got the script working thanks to user3439894. 

But it still doesn't update the creation date... 

MXF: created 05.01.2014 06:49, modified 05.01.2014 06:50 

mov: created 23.06.2016 05:34, modified 05.01.2014 06:50

Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: You have way to much going on in this question and Stack Overflow is probably a better place to be asking.  That said I'd modify the question to have only one code block about what you're trying to attempt and then follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example}(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to include with that code block.  Also include in the info the output of `ls -l` for the target directory.  Continued in next comment...

Comment: Additionally with a handful of `$filename.MXF` and `$filename.mov` files where `$filename` matched each set of `.MXF` and `.mov` files, I tested #1 as `for f in *.MXF; do touch -r "$f" "${f%MXF}mov"; done` and it worked fine!  So what problem are you having with it? Note that the `.MXF` files cannot be `.mxf` as this is case sensitive. Same goes for `.mov`, it must be that and not `.MOV`. (Which is why I said include the output of ls -l for the target directory.)

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you for your information. ls -l is showing -rwxrwxrwx for all files inside the folder and drwxrwxrwx for the folder. If #1 works fine for you (and apparently lots of other people) what am I doing wrong to get "touch: *.MXF: No such file or directory"?

Comment: When you run the code from #1 are you in the directory containing the `.MXF` and `.mov` files?  BTW I didn't ask just if the permissions on all the files were the same! I asked for the output of `ls -l` for the target directory so I could actually see the names of the files, etc.  Additionally this is why I said you have way to much going on in this question and to limit it to one code block and provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can't possibly expect us to help if we don't have all the relevant facts!

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer. I inserted all the code I found to give an overview what I tried and find the best solution for what I want to do...
I will know edit the whole question, just a second...

Comment: Creation date is specific to the HFS+ file system. When trying to change this metadata on a foreign file system your mileage may vary. Your `touch` command only operates on access and modification time which should change change time, not creation time. `SetFile` is the tool that you need to use.

Comment: @fd0 Do you have an example how to get what I want with SetFile? Thank you for the info.

Comment: @fd0, Using `GetFileInfo -d $filename.mov`, which gets the creation date, shows the same for `$filename.mov` after running `for f in *.MXF; do touch -r "$f" "${f%MXF}mov"; done` as it does for `$filename.MXF`. So why is `SetFile` needed?

Comment: @user3439894 You are correct. My bad, I didn't test `touch -r`, I read the manual which is incorrect.

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you for clarifying. Do you know if I did something wrong by creating the script? How did you ran it?

Comment: @phramenma, In Terminal I `cd` to the directory containing the `.MXF` and `.mov` files and then on the command line used exactly: `for f in *.MXF; do touch -r "$f" "${f%MXF}mov"; done`

Comment: @user3439894 This seems to be working! BUT it still doesn't update the creation date... MXF: created 05.01.2014 06:49, modified 05.01.2014 06:50 – mov: created 23.06.05:34, modified 05.01.2014 06:50 Is there any way to  correct this?

Comment: @phramenma, In Terminal, what is the output of: `uname -a; bash --version`

Comment: @user3439894 Here's the output: Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is not working for you I'm going to suggest you do as fd0 suggested and use `SetFile`.  This will be used in conjunction with `GetFileInfo`, both of which are a part of Command Line Tools for Xcode.

You do not need to install the Xcode.app which is ~3.80 GB, just ~160 MB for Command Line Tools for Xcode.

In Terminal: `xcode-select --install`

See [How to Install Command Line Tools in OS X Mavericks & Yosemite (Without Xcode)](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/), which is also for OS X El Capitan.

Here is a bash script to use with `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do

    if [[ -f $f ]] && [[ ${f##*.} == MXF ]] && [[ -f ${f%.*}.mov ]]; then

        cDate="$(GetFileInfo -d "$f")"
        mDate="$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")"

        SetFile -d "$cDate" -m "$mDate" "${f%.*}.mov"

    fi

done
```

---

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing these files do not reside on a HFS+ file system as I said earlier YMMV.

Comment: @fd0, Unfortunately phramenma didn't say where the files reside or what filesystem. `for f in *.MXF; do touch -r "$f" "${f%MXF}mov"; done` works just fine for me on an HFS+ filesystem. Both `stat` and `GetFileInfo` confirms it works for me without the need to use `SetFile`. Si since it not working it easier for me to offer a `SetFile` solution as I have a few times in the past with other posts.

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you so much for your great help. I really appreciate it and the time you spend on my problems. :/ The files are stored on an exFat-HDD. But unfortunately the original code just copied the modification date. Your new script just did the trick! Thank you again!!! P.S. Which application did you use in the screenshot?

Comment: @phramenma, You're welcome, glad I could help.  I used [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com) and use it for some of my scripting needs.

Comment: @@phramenma, I added another _test_ to the beginning of my `if` _statement_: `if [[ -f "$f" ]] &&  ...`, just for good measure.  This way whatever is in the directory only if it's a normal file ending in `.MXF` and has a corresponding  `.mov` file will GetFileInfo get the creation date-time and modified date-time and apply them to the target file.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to copy modification date to creation date on same files you can use my modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do


    cDate="$(GetFileInfo -d "$f")"
    mDate="$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")"

    SetFile -d "$mDate" "$f"


done
```